# change the color column of the same series C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2012, charts

I have a chart1 object and I add a series to it, with n columns. I want columns to be painted red or green based on certain criteria.

I have the following code for the if but for example all of them are painted green even though I have gone through the if.

I already used breakpoints and if it goes through the if and else but it doesn't paint the columns as I want.

```
//maximum line
StripLine linea = new StripLine();
linea.StripWidth = 0;
linea.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
linea.BorderWidth = 2;
linea.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
linea.IntervalOffset = 75;
linea.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines.Add(linea);

//minimum line
StripLine lineaM = new StripLine();
lineaM.StripWidth = 0;
lineaM.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
lineaM.BorderWidth = 2;
lineaM.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
lineaM.IntervalOffset = 45;
lineaM.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines.Add(lineaM);

chart1.Series.Clear();
chart1.Series.Add("Series1");
chart1.Series["Series1"].BorderWidth = 3;
chart1.Titles.Clear();
chart1.Titles.Add("Total changes");
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 100;

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count;i++)
{
    string qty = dt.Rows[i]["PID"].ToString();
    if (Convert.ToInt32(qty) > 45)//if it is greater than the minimum, the column must be red
    {
        chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "MES";
        chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "PID";
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.Red;
    }
    else //otherwise it must be green
    {
        chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "MES";
        chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "PID";
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.Green;
    }
}

chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;

//chart1.ChartAreas["ChartData"]
chart1.DataSource = dt;
chart1.DataBind();
```

For example March should be red because it exceeds the minimum line:
[image: chart]

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Because April is green you set the whole series to green. If you remove April data they will all be red. You need to set the color of individual columns, not the whole series.

Comment: @PalleDue How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the chart component you are using, but apparently points can be customized after they are data bound, by calling an event handler. It looks like you have to do something like this:

```cs
private void CustomizeBarColours(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count;i++)
    {
        string qty = dt.Rows[i]["PID"].ToString();
        if (Convert.ToInt32(qty) > 45)//if it is greater than the minimum, the column must be red
        {
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[i].Color = Color.Red;
        }
        else //otherwise it must be green
        {
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[i].Color = Color.Green;
        }
    }
}
```

Watch out for index out of range, it's not very elegant the way `i` is used to index into both `Rows` and `Points`.

Then after your DataBind you can add:

```cs
chart1.Customize += CustomizeBarColours;
```

These two lines from the for loop, you need to do only once:

```cs
chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "MES";
chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "PID";
```

And then you can remove your for loop altogether.

Comment: you are right now the error is:
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.